# Write_Prometheus plugin with basic auth

Tags: prometheus, grafana, collectd

I am testing the below Write_Prometheus plugin to send the cassandra metrics to prometheus server which is external machine but i see that all metrics are sending without any basic auth happening. so i need help here that how i can send my metrics using basic auth to prometheus server . https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Write_Prometheus

I try to add auth file under the Write_Prometheus plugin and restarted the plugin but it didn't help so looking some idea that how i can enforce basic auth while sending the metrics to propemetus server.